# How can I make apache use PHP over passenger by default?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

Here's my setup: I have an apache server running a number of virtual hosts, each of them using PHP. I now have a rails app I want to install to a subdirectory for one of the sites (a subdomain would be adequate as a fall-back).

From what I've read so far, as soon as I install `libapache2-mod-passenger` all the sites by default will use passenger rather than PHP. Is there a way around this, barring setting a `PassengerEnabled off` directive in each site config file?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the way Apache deals with preprocessor/executable-code modules. PHP will be interpreted by the module designated to handle PHP scripts. Passenger/Ruby applications must be explicitly configured (all requests for the specified directory is handed over to Passenger).  If you do not explicitly configure a directory to be handled through Passenger it is handled according to the remainder of your Apache configuration.

Comment: there seems to be a lot of conflicting information on this, with many articles claiming that PHP gets uninstalled when passenger is installed.

Comment: I'm not sure where the people writing those articles are getting their information - there is nothing mutually exclusive about the two technologies (I have production servers with PHP, Passenger, and mod_perl all coexisting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [these instructions](http://russbrooks.com/2009/5/25/install-ubuntu-9-04-server-edition-rails-php-passenger-postgresql-and-mysql), I installed passenger as a gem. The instructions omitted the need to run `passenger-install-apache2-module` which basically walked me through the entire process.

With this setup, PHP is untouched, and Rails apps can even be configured to run in subfolders within a PHP site.